# .sh script not finding php?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, php, php-cli

I have this code in a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
php -f email_processor.php 'Corgi Boy' https://www.domain.com/corgi-boy/ domain.com https://www.domain.art Site Title
```

As a test, I ran it from the command line and received the following error:

```
run_email_processor.sh: line 2: php: command not found
```

How do I make `php` available to the script?

The script is running via AT job with user `www:www`.
The AT job is attempting to execute the script as expected.

I believe the problem is either syntax on line 2 or “php” is unknown to bash for some reason.

I tested the script as `root` user.

Comment: *Should* it find Php? Have you installed it?

Comment: Just use the full path to php, wherever that is.

Comment: I elected to put the full path in the environment file. Works now. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the `php-cli` package:

```
sudo apt install php-cli
```

If you already have PHP CLI installed, you have to use `update-alternatives` to set the system default.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
```